# Trying to Make Endless Runner C++ with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I have an array of cube objects initialised like so (index 0 not used here as that's for the player):

```
game_object[1] = new GameObject();
game_object[1]->setPosition(vec3(7.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

game_object[2] = new GameObject();
game_object[2]->setPosition(vec3(14.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

game_object[3] = new GameObject();
game_object[3]->setPosition(vec3(21.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

game_object[4] = new GameObject();
game_object[4]->setPosition(vec3(36.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

game_object[5] = new GameObject();
game_object[5]->setPosition(vec3(42.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

I have a render function in which they are drawn:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3 * INDICES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

In my update they move to the left as expected. To do this I am just adding another vector to their positions:

```
for (int i = 1; i < MAX_CUBES; i++)
{
    game_object[i]->setPosition(game_object[i]->getPosition() + vec3(-0.03, 0.0, 0.00));
}
```

However, I want the cubes to repeat this until the user exits the game. I made a reset function to send them back to their starting positions:

```
void Game::reset()
{
    game_object[0]->setPosition(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    game_object[1]->setPosition(vec3(7.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    game_object[2]->setPosition(vec3(14.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    game_object[3]->setPosition(vec3(21.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    game_object[4]->setPosition(vec3(36.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));   
    game_object[5]->setPosition(vec3(42.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

This function gets called in the update when the final cube's position is off screen to the left:

```
if (game_object[5]->getPosition().x <= 0.0)
{
    reset();
}
```

However, this isn't working. Nothing resets after the last cube goes to the left.

Comment: These are only a few lines of code and the error might be elsewhere. This doesn't mean you should post the whole code, instead provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reducing your program to the most basic elements.

Comment: Please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What are `GameObject`? Are they those cubes? Where do those code snippets belong? Where's the drawing function?

Comment: 1. Does running `reset` on it's own work correctly?
2. Does `game_object[5]->getPosition().x` return a proper value?

Comment: @Samleo getPosition() returns the correct value however they are not resetting to their starting positions when the restart function is called.

Comment: Small fragmented bits of code are difficult to give a certain solution to, and I can't run anything to check. Something like a gamedev forum is better suited to on-going discussion and possibly larger code blocks / compilable examples. I also feel maybe your overall approach is over-complicating it, and a discussion board is a better place for "consider this" responses.

Comment: Does setPosition() even work properly? If not, your issue is there

Comment: Hmm.. As a game developer I have a slight suspicion that you actually moved the thing to the correct position BUT ** forgot to render** and display it afterward...

Comment: I think the whole approach to the problem could be different since you are subordinating logic to graphics (or at least so it seems from your snippets). You should have a world coordinate system in which you move the cubes and then decide how these are mapped to actual rendered objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are using `game_object` here but looks very error prone. If you have `MAX_CUBES = 5` (as you do have 5 cubes), then that for-loop will miss the last one. Adding further objects (e.g. for gaps, vertical rules, hazards, etc.) will make it even more so.

```
for (int i = 1; i < MAX_CUBES; i++)
{
    game_object[i]->setPosition(game_object[i]->getPosition() + vec3(-0.03, 0.0, 0.00));
}
```

If `MAX_CUBES` = 5, then it will move index 1, 2, 3, 4, and not 5, which is the one you check in the condition. 5 will just stay at `42` permanently (is that off-screen?).

Stepping through the code in a debugger will make a problem like this pretty clear regardless, and is an essential tool for programming. Maybe the code just never reaches the `if (game_object[5]->getPosition().x <= 0.0)` check in the first place? Is there any `return` in that update function, or is that condition inside another one of some sorts?

Answer (score 0):

Because in your comment you noted that `game_object[5]->getPosition().x` returns a correct value, the most likely problem is with your `reset()` function and the `setPosition` function you are using.

**1. Check if set position is working in the first place**

Perhaps there is an error with `setPosition()`.
After you set the position using `setPosition()` and then log the object's coordinates using `getPosition()` does it return the position you expect?

If not, something is wrong with `setPosition`.

If so, then...

**2. You probably changed the position but failed to render it!**
This is a very common problem lol

There is a very high chance you changed the position of the object **BUT didn't update what's shown on the screen!**

**3. Side note for scalability**

There is a much more efficient and scalable way of doing a reset if you have eventually have more than 5 objects, by placing their reset values in an array and looping through them:

```
#define MAX_CUBES 6
double resetPositions_x[MAX_CUBES] = {0.0, 7.0, 14.0, 21.0, 36.0, 42.0};

void Game::reset()
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_CUBES;i++){
        game_object[i]->setPosition(vec3(resetPositions_x[i], 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
}
```

(Also, it seems every x reset position is a multiple of 7 except 36.0 -> is that a mistake?)